# Herança com interface

Tags: .net, orientação-a-objetos, visual-studio, herança, interface

Como eu poderia resolver o seguinte problema.

**Cenário:** Tenho uma classe B que herda da classe A e implementa a interface I.

**Problema:** A interface I obriga a implementação do método X que por sua vez é implementado na classe A, e não na B.

O Visual Studio não reconhece essa implementação por parte do pai, o que devo fazer?

Comment: Se B herda de A, o método está implementado em A, não há como ele não existir em B. Pode dar mais informações, postar o código?

Comment: Sim, o método esta em B porem ele não reconhece esse método na implementação da interface I.

Comment: O método está com a mesma assinatura (mesmos parâmetros, declaração idêntica)? Poste o código de A, B e I.

Comment: Foi erro meu, a interface estava recebendo, como parâmetro, um int? e não um int. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @bfavaretto, porque você colocou em suspenso?

Comment: @HarryPotter Por causa do comentário do autor logo acima. Ele cometeu um erro na interface, que não aparece na pergunta pois ela não inclui o código.

Comment: @bfavaretto está em discussão no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1527/6026

Comment: Só pra constar, um desses votos de abrir é meu, e eu cliquei errado ao tentar clicar na tag herança. Não concordo com a abertura.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Cenário:***

```cs
public class B: A
{

}
public class A: I
{

    public object X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public interface I
{
    object X { get; set; }
}
```

***Utilizando:***

```cs
B b = new B();
b.X = 10;
```

Ou seja, `B` herdou todo comportamento de `A`, mesmo tendo um contrato com `I`, então, `B` possui também o `X`.